# Group A Column Series with WPF Charting Toolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, toolkit

I got a Column Series that looks like this: [image]

As you can see i got lots of columns, that I need to group somehow. A group consists out of 1 shuttle and for  each shuttle there are 5 nests. My preferred form of grouping would be a, the nest written underneath each column and the shuttle again underneath. Between groups there should be a vertical line or some space to separate them. If this isn't possible I would greatly appreciate any other suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a datatable with a column for each nest( so total five columns) , add five column series to the chart , DependentValueBinding to each column name, set ItemsSource to datatable( same for each column series).

Let me know if you want the code.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, we solved our problem already by using visifire.